# How to report an error for garbage value mentioned in XML file while reading it?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

Actually i am resolving some defect, where customer requirement is for given xml configuration file, any thing written apart from tag it should show some error for that including line number and property name.
But SAX parser is not reporting it, as per it xml is valid.
I can better explain my problem via below example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <addresslist>
  <company>
    <address>500 Oracle Parkway,
             Redwood Shores, CA 94065
    </address>
  </company>
  <!-- ... -->
  <employee>
    <lastname>King</lastname>    $$$ Some Garbage value here should report an error while parsing
    <address>101, Bombay</address>
  </employee>
  <!-- ... -->
</addresslist>
```

Above xml is valid as per XML parser, but having some garbage value in it.
Any solution would be helpful..

I believe XML is correct but requirement is that,with in XML there should not be any single text apart from defined tag, if any text found apart from given tag XML should consider it as a garbage value.and report it with line number.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with XML shown. Please [edit] post to clarify why you believe otherwise and preferable show code ([MCVE]) that you using. Consider also tagging post with language you are using.

Comment: any update team.. please suggest it anybody having any idea.